# Home no such file or folder in terminal

Tags: home-directory, cd-command

I'm trying to go to Downloads directory, the dir is showing in the list but not able to open it in terminal.

```
ajl1254@ajl1254:/home$ ls ~/
Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public  Templates
Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  snap    Videos
ajl1254@ajl1254:/home$ cd /Downloads
bash: cd: /Downloads: No such file or directory
ajl1254@ajl1254:/home$ cd ./Downloads
bash: cd: ./Downloads: No such file or directory
ajl1254@ajl1254:/home$ cd ./downlads
bash: cd: ./downlads: No such file or directory
ajl1254@ajl1254:/home$
```

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** located in ~  (your $HOME directory, ie. /home/$USER/)

Your commands are trying to enter the directory /home/Downloads/ or /home/downloads/ instead

use `cd` alone to change to your $HOME directory, then your entered commands will work, *OR* use `cd ~/Downloads`

Comment: use cd alone to change to your $HOME directory, then your entered commands will work, or use cd ~/Downloads -It works. Thanks you